# Why does my UV unwrapping in a different way than the book?

Tags: uv

I'm training on a model from a book. And the book tells me how to seam the model.
Now, I've unwrapped models before but just for training's sake I'm trying to do it his way.

Here is what the book tells me to do:
[image]

But when I do it, result is as follows:
[image]

Here's my own way to seam:
[image]

My question is why does the second picture produces that jumbled mess on UV and not the clean projection we see in the first?
What is the reason behind that?

- Could it have been because the book is old and the new Blender release(I'm using 2.81) unwraps it differently?
- Could it be that he is using some projection method without informing me?
- Could it be that my mesh doesn't exactly match his, so the result is different?